# vba > form > show userform with button without focus

Tags: excel, vba

The button always has focus

[image]

Is there a way to start my form without focus on the button?

[image]

Comment: go to button's properties and set "Tab stop" to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatically if you need to remove focus you can use the `Tab Stop` property to remove that,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  CommandButton1.TabStop = False   

End Sub
```

Or as @Máté Juhász, go into properties and select `false`,

[image]